# List<comma-separated strings> => List<string>?

Tags: c#, linq

Trying to come up with a LINQy way to do this, but nothing's coming to me.

I have a List<> of objects which include a property which is a comma-separated list of alpha codes:

```
lst[0].codes = "AA,BB,DD"
lst[1].codes = "AA,DD,EE"
lst[2].codes = "GG,JJ"
```

I'd like a list of those codes, hopefully in the form of a List of strings:

```
result = AA,BB,DD,EE,GG,JJ
```

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Like this `lst.SelectMany(x => x.Split(',')).Distinct().ToList()` but with a better CSV parsing...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, rather depends if the data is from a CSV file. OP doesn's say of the strings could contain escaped commas.

Comment: Thanks, @AdrianoRepetti.  The simple string.split() is sufficient parsing for these purposes.

Comment: @Jodrell agree but I feel better if I remind him that String.Split() is not CSV parsing (just in case...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx) to get all **split codes** and use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) to not repeat the values.
Try something like this:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(x => x.codes.Split(",")).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Joel.  Never used SelectMany() before.

Comment: @johnpaz Of course you explicitly asked for a `List<>`, but you could also use a *set* or something, which cannot have duplicates, as in `var result = new SortedSet<string>(lst.SelectMany(x => x.codes.Split(",")));`.

Comment: This is really nice. However, I have a question: why `.Distinct()`? Did the user ask for it to be Distinct? In the second `lst[1].codes` index, wouldn't you be removing `AA`?

Comment: @MarkBuffalo: In the original question items AA and DD appear twice in the inputs but only once in the outputs. The logical conclusion is that the original poster wished to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @johnpaz: A careful study of the available overloads of SelectMany will pay dividends; it is in some sense the foundational operation on sequences. As an exercise: can you implement the same functionality as Select but only using SelectMany?  How about Where?  How about Join?  None of these will be as fast as the purpose-built equivalents, but this exercise illustrates that SelectMany is a powerful tool in your toolbox.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split each string into multiple strings. Then you need to use [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to concatenate multiple sequences into a single sequence, and then you need to use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to remove duplicates.

```
var result =
    lst
    .SelectMany(x => x.codes.Split(','))
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need a `string` as a result:

```
string result = string.Join(",",lst.SelectMany(p=>p.codes.Split(",")).Distinct());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  List<string> list = new List<string>();

  char[] sep = new char[1];
  sep[0] = ',';
  foreach (string item in lst)
  {
       list.AddRange(item.Split(sep));
  }

  list = list.Distinct().ToList();
```